# Why don't you grow up?

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

## Why don't you grow up?

In the past week a meme involving the young actor Aaron Bailey became trending in most Brazilian social networks. Entitled "why don't you grow up" it consists in repeating a sentence replacing its vowels with `i`s (it's a bit more complicated than that, I'll explain below). As I want to be a cool guy I decided to write a program that `mimimifies` a given string.

[image]

## Challenge

The challenge consists of `mimimifying` a string, following the rules:

- `ão` and `õe` should be replaced with `im`.
- `ca`, `ka`, `que`, `ke`, `qui`, `ki`, `co` ,`ko`, `cu`, and `ku` should be replaced with `ki`.
- `ça`, `ce`, `çe`, `ci`, `çi`, `ço`, and `çu` should be replaced with `ci`.
- `ga`, `gue`, `gui`, `go`, and `gu` should be replaced with `gui`.
- `ja`, `ge`, `je`, `gi`, `ji`, `jo`, and `ju` should be replaced with `ji`
- You can assume that `qua`, `quo`, `quu`, `gua`, `guo`, and `guu`, will never appear, only `a` and `o` can have tildes and if they do they'll be followed by `o` and `e`, repsectively (`ão`, `õe`).
- The only time `u`s are allowed in output strings is `gui`, besides that case all other vowels present should be `i`s.
- In all other circumstances all vowels must be replaced with `i`s.
- Other than tilde all other accents may be ignored.
- Two or more `i`s in a row are not allowed, you should replace them with only one (`Piauiense` -> `Pinsi`)

## Examples

**Input**

```
Por que você só fala assim?
```

**Output**

```
pir ki vici si fili issim?
```

**Input**

```
Que horas são?
```

**Output**

```
ki hiris sim?
```

**Input**

```
Óculos sem lente pode ser armação
```

**Output**

```
ikilis sim linti pidi sir irmicim
```

**Input**

```
Ganha o código com menos bytes
```

**Output**

```
guinhi i kidigui kim minis bytis
```

## Rules

- The vowels are `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, and `u`.
- You can see the full list of possible accents [here](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/psu/portuguese/).
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the shortest code in bytes wins. Check meta if counting bytes is awkward in your language.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/30231) are forbidden
- Your output must be consistent in case: all upper/all lower.
- You may assume the input to be in whichever encoding you want but if you do you must specify it.

**Happy golfing!**/**Hippy guilfing!**

Comment: (This phenomenon sounds similar to [Ermahgerd](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ermahgerd) in English.)

Comment: What is the list of accented characters?

Comment: @Mego why? By ignored I meant there presence is irrelevant (`ê` == `e`, `ó` == `o`)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 150 bytes

```
[ÀÁÂàáâ]
a
[ÉÊéê]
e
Í|í
i
[ÓÔóô]
o
[ÚÜúü]
u
T`L`l
ão|õe
im
[ck][aou]|qu[ei]|ke
ki
ç[aeiou]|ce
ci
g[aou]|gue
gui
j[aeou]|g[ei]
ji
(gu)i|[aeou]
$1i
ii
i
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=W8OAw4HDgsOgw6HDol0KYQpbw4nDisOpw6pdCmUKw418w60KaQpbw5PDlMOzw7RdCm8KW8Oaw5zDusO8XQp1ClRgTGBsCsOjb3zDtWUKaW0KW2NrXVthb3VdfHF1W2VpXXxrZQpraQrDp1thZWlvdV18Y2UKY2kKZ1thb3VdfGd1ZQpndWkKalthZW91XXxnW2VpXQpqaQooZ3UpaXxbYWVvdV0KJDFpCmlpCmk&input=UG9yIHF1ZSB2b2PDqiBzw7MgZmFsYSBhc3NpbT8KUXVlIGhvcmFzIHPDo28_CsOTY3Vsb3Mgc2VtIGxlbnRlIHBvZGUgc2VyIGFybWHDp8OjbwpHYW5oYSBvIGPDs2RpZ28gY29tIG1lbm9zIGJ5dGVz)

This is my first Retina program, so there's probably a lot of improvements to make. Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks to Martin for correcting some mistakes and for some golfing suggestions.

### Explanation

I'm going to break up the explanation into 3 sections, to make it easier on me.

#### Section 1: Preprocessing

```
[ÀÁÂàáâ]
a
[ÉÊéê]
e
Í|í
i
[ÓÔóô]
o
[ÚÜúü]
u
T`L`l
```

The first 5 rules replace any accented vowel with the corresponding unaccented version. It's shorter to list out the matches in character classes (or, in the third case, as two options) than to use the culture-invariance and case-insentivity options each time. The last rule converts all ASCII letters to lowercase.

#### Section 2: Mimimification

```
ão|õe
im
[ck][aou]|qu[ei]|ke
ki
ç[aeiou]|ce
ci
g[aou]|gue
gui
j[aeou]|g[ei]
ji
```

These rules simply apply the substitutions specified.

#### Section 3: Cleanup

```
(gu)i|[aeou]
$1i
i+
i
```

The first rule matches any vowel except for the `u` in `gui`, and replaces them with `i`s. The second rule removes repeated `i`s.

Comment: What better language is there than one that is based on regex  :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>396</s> <s>392</s> 389 bytes (<s>383</s> <s>379</s> 376 characters)

Too many `replace`s, too much regex, ...

```
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/ão|õe/g,"im").replace(/[àâá]/g,"a").replace(/é|ê/g,"e").replace(/í/g,"i").replace(/ó|ô/g,"o").replace(/ú|ü/g,"u").replace(/(k[aeou])|(c[aou])|que|qui/g,"ki").replace(/(ç[aeiou])|ce/g,"ci").replace(/(g[aou])|gue/g,"gui").replace(/(j[aeou])|ge/g,"ji").split("gui").map(function(a){return a.replace(/[aeou]/g,"i")}).join("gui").replace(/i{2,}/g,"i")
```

I have used this [link](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/psu/portuguese/) for a list of Brazilian accented letters so that I know for which letters I have to remove the accent.

#### Explanation

```
s.toLowerCase()
```

First, everything is converted to lowercase.

```
.replace(/ão|õe/g,"im")
```

Then I'm am implementing this rule.

```
.replace(/[àâá]/g,"a").replace(/é|ê/g,"e").replace(/í/g,"i").replace(/ó|ô/g,"o").replace(/ú|ü/g,"u")
```

Then the accents are removed using regex.

```
.replace(/(k[aeou])|(c[aou])|que|qui/g,"ki").replace(/(ç[aeiou])|ce/g,"ci").replace(/(g[aou])|gue/g,"gui").replace(/(j[aeou])|ge/g,"ji").split("gui")
```

After that, the the string is being bombarded by regular expressions to "memify" it.

```
.split("gui").map(function(a){return a.replace(/[aeou]/g,"i")}).join("gui")
```

Now all the vowels, except those in `gui` (that is why I used `split`) are being converted to `i`. After that, I rejoin the Array using `gui` as the delimiter.

```
.replace(/i{2,}/g,"i")
```

Finally, I am replacing 2 or more `i`s with just 1 of them.

## Snack Snippet!

```js
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/ão|õe/g,"im").replace(/[àâá]/g,"a").replace(/é|ê/g,"e").replace(/í/g,"i").replace(/ó|ô/g,"o").replace(/ú|ü/g,"u").replace(/(k[aeou])|(c[aou])|que|qui/g,"ki").replace(/(ç[aeiou])|ce/g,"ci").replace(/(g[aou])|gue/g,"gui").replace(/(j[aeou])|ge/g,"ji").split("gui").map(function(a){return a.replace(/[aeou]/g,"i")}).join("gui").replace(/i{2,}/g,"i")

console.log(f("Por que você só fala assim?"))
console.log(f("Que horas são?"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           //They call me the professional Brazilian-meme-maker
console.log(f("Óculos sem lente pode ser armação"))                                                                                                                                                                             //dank memes, dank memes everywhere
console.log(f("Ganha o código com menos bytes"))
```

Golfing suggestions are welcome